# Oracle Forms Builder: When compiling oracle forms builder goes down

Tags: oracle, forms

When I compile all my form (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>) the oracle forms builder goes down or crashes.

I don't know if this information is relevant but I'm working in a Virtual Machine with the following settings:

- Linux Operating System
- 8192 Mb Base Memory
- 2 Processors

Anyways I tested in windows machine and Oracle Forms Builder crashes when I try to compile all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to open the form, save it, close the builder and reopen it.
2. Try to open/save the form in another machine and reopen it in the machine that crashes.
3. If you use plls, recompile them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) and retry.
4. Don't use plx built in a windows machine or another version of linux.